# how can I extract the standard error from the random effects of JointModel?

Tags: r

1. Model joint Risque compétitifs
   1.1. linear mixed model

```
mod_mml=lme(MDRD~DELAI_MONTH, data=Mixed, random=~1+DELAI_MONTH|N_ID,na.action=na.exclude)
```

1.2. Competing Risks joint model with two competing risks being death and transplantation

```
SurvieCR=crLong(Survie,"Statut1_60m","Vivant 60m")
```

1.3. however, for the survival model we need to use the data in the long format, and include the competing risks indicator as a stratification factor.

```
Surv_comp=coxph(Surv(DELAI_M,status2) ~ 1*strata + strata(strata),
                data=SurvieCR, x=TRUE,method="efron",na.action=na.exclude)
```

1.4. the corresponding joint model is fitted simply by including the above two submodels as main arguments, setting argument CompRisk to TRUE

```
JM_comp=jointModel(mod_mml, Surv_comp, timeVar="DELAI_MONTH",
                   method="spline-PH-aGH",
                   interFact=list(value= ~ strata, data=SurvieCR),
                   CompRisk=TRUE)
```

2. results random effects, I tested

```
summary(JM_comp)
random.effects(JM_comp)
coef(JM_comp) 
coef(JM_comp, process = "Longitudinal") ....etc
```

3. example of the output

```
  random.effects(JM_comp)
     (Intercept)   DELAI_MONTH
1    3.727740214 -0.2020818077
2    1.070965087  0.0370529800
3    3.440276448  0.1582811172
4   -4.551210225 -0.1568204062
5   -2.943917109 -0.0389127841
```

4. but I need the standard deviation of each intercept and of each slope. if someone can help me?thank you very much

Comment: Can we have  a [mcve] please? I would use one of the examples from `?JM::jointModel`, but none of these are simple random-slopes models as far as I can see ...

Comment: The short/incomplete answer is that `ranef(JM_comp, postVar = TRUE)` will get you an object with the components that you need to figure this out, but unpacking the object is a little tricky. If you post a reproducible example I can try to illustrate what you need to do.  (Also, please clarify whether you need the standard deviations on the group-level *differences* from the population effects or on the group-level *estimates*, i.e. the std devs of `random.effects()` or of `coef()` ...)

Comment: I tried to make a small reproducible example but it doesn't work. I have an unbalanced database of 565 patients each with different creatinine numbers that have been followed for 5 years. I need the standard deviations of the intercepts and the standard deviations of the slopes for each patient, i.e. ramdon.effects( ).    thank you very much.

Comment: this is the program:
#linear mixed model fit (random intercepts)
mod_mml=lme(MDRD~DELAI_MONTH, data=Mixed, andom=~1+DELAI_MONTH|N_ID,
            na.action=na.exclude)
# Competing Risks joint model
SurvieCR=crLong(Survie,"Statut1_60m","Vivant 60m")
Surv_comp=coxph(Surv(DELAI_M,status2) ~ 1*strata + strata(strata),data=SurvieCR, x=TRUE,method="efron",na.action=na.exclude) 
# joint Model
JM_comp=jointModel(mod_mml, Surv_comp, timeVar="DELAI_MONTH", method="spline-PH-aGH", interFact=list(value= ~ strata, data=SurvieCR), CompRisk=TRUE)
# randon.effect
random.effects(JM_comp) .